# Kotlin: How to flatten list of Hashmaps

Tags: kotlin

How can I flatten a list of `HashMap`s in Kotlin?

```
var listOfMaps: List<Map<String, String>> = listOf(mapOf("test" to "test1"), mapOf("test2" to "test3"), mapOf("test4" to "test5"))
```

I would like to `get:Map<String,String>` with all key value paires

Comment: what do you want to do with duplicated keys (but differing values)?

Comment: by the way: what did you try so far?

Comment: @Roland duplicate keys... That's actually a good point. None of the answers seem to cover that. OP may need to clarify if there can be duplicate keys.

Answer (score 7):

```
val map:Map<String, String> = listOfMaps
    .flatMap { it.entries }
    .associate { it.key to it.value }
```

Comment: instead of `.map { it.key to it.value }.toMap()`  you could also just use: `.associate { it.key to it.value }`

Comment: I had to append `.asSequence()` to `it.entries` to make it work.

Answer (score 4):

you can do something like this if you don't know if the list can be empty.

```
val map = listOfMaps.fold(mapOf<String, String>()) {acc, value -> acc + value }
```

If the list never will be empty you can use `reduce` instead.

Thank you Demigod for the comments

Comment: Why do you need `folrdRight` here and not just `fold`? Also `+` operation creates new map every time....

Comment: You could also use `fold` as well and it will be the same result

Comment: Yes, it will give the same result, but it provides unneeded complexity. `foldRight` starts from the last item and move towards previous ones, while `fold` just goes in a simple `for` loop. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `fold`:

```
listOfMaps.fold(
        mutableMapOf<String, String>(),
        { acc, item -> acc.also { it.putAll(item) } }
)
```

The first parameter `mutableMapOf<String, String>()` creates an empty map to put the values into.  This is called the accumulator

The second parameter is a function which takes two arguments

1. The accumulator
2. An item from the original list

This function is run sequentially against all items in the list.  In our case it adds all the items from each map to the accumulator.

Note: This function does not account for duplicate keys. If a later map has the same key as an earlier one then the value just gets overridden.

Also note (pun intended): We use `acc.also {}` as we want to return the actual map, not the return value from the `addAll` method

Answer (score 2):

Well... seeing lots of solutions, I will add my two cents here:

If you don't mind losing the values of duplicated keys you can use something as follows:

```
listOfMaps.flatMap { it.entries }.associate{ it.key to it.value } // or: it.toPair() if you will
// depending on how large those lists can become, you may want to consider also using asSequence
```

If you instead want to collect all entries including duplicate keys (i.e. saving all the values), use the following instead (which then gives you a `Map<String, List<String>>`):

```
listOfMaps.flatMap { it.entries }.groupBy({ it.key }) { it.value }
```

Also here the comment regarding `asSequence` holds...

Finally if you can omit those maps within the list and just use a `Pair` instead, that will spare you the `flatMap { it.entries }`-call and make things even easier, e.g. you could just call `.toMap()` then for the first case and `groupBy` directly for the second and the question regarding `asSequence` no longer arises.

Answer (score 0):

An extra addition to this, if you have single value maps, maybe you want to switch to a `List<Prair<String, String>>`. In that case, the solution  is straight forward:

You would have something like:

```
var listOfMaps: List<Pair<String, String>> = listOf("test" to "test1", "test2" to "test3", "test4" to "test5")
```

and `toMap()` would dsolve it all:

```
listOfMaps.toMap()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have duplicate keys or don't care for them, you can do it like this:

```
val flattenedMap = listOfMaps.flatMap { it.toList() }.toMap()
```

---

If you have duplicate keys and care for them, you can do it like this:

```
val flattenedMap = mutableMapOf<String, MutableList<String>>().apply {
    listOfMaps.flatMap { it.toList() }.forEach {
        getOrPut(it.first) {
            mutableListOf()
        }.add(it.second)
    }
}
```

The result will be `Map<String, List<String>>` then of course.

Comment: the first approach is very short and ok... but the second should rather be `groupBy` instead ;-) wrote my answer, while you wrote yours it seems ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This solution works with same keys (and different collection as values) by merging them together instead of overwriting them

```kotlin
/**
 * Merge two maps with lists
 */
fun <K,V>Map<K,Collection<V>>.mergeLists(other: Map<K,Collection<V>>) =
    (this.keys + other.keys).associateWith {key ->
        setOf(this[key], other[key]).filterNotNull()
    }.mapValues { (_,b) -> b.flatten().distinct() }

/**
 * Merge two maps with sets
 */
fun <K,V>Map<K,Collection<V>>.mergeSets(other: Map<K,Collection<V>>) =
    (this.keys + other.keys).associateWith {key ->
        setOf(this[key], other[key]).filterNotNull()
    }.mapValues { (_,b) -> b.flatten().toSet() }
```

Then use like e.g. `listOfMaps.reduce { a, b -> a.mergeSets(b) }`

Test:

```kotlin
@Test
fun `should merge two maps with as lists or sets`() {

    // GIVEN
    val map1 = mapOf(
        "a" to listOf(1, 2, 3),
        "b" to listOf(4, 5, 6),
        "c" to listOf(10),
        "e" to emptyList()
    )

    val map2 = mapOf(
        "a" to listOf(1, 9),
        "b" to listOf(7),
        "d" to listOf(null)
    )

    // WHEN
    val mergedAsLists = map1.mergeLists(map2)
    val mergedAsSets = map1.mergeSets(map2)

    // THEN
    listOf(mergedAsLists, mergedAsSets).forEach { merged ->
        assertThat(merged.keys).containsOnly("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
        assertThat(merged["a"]).containsOnly(1,2,3,9)
        assertThat(merged["b"]).containsOnly(4,5,6,7)
        assertThat(merged["c"]).containsOnly(10)
        assertThat(merged["d"]).containsOnly(null)
        assertThat(merged["e"]).isEmpty()
    }

}
```